# Array to image with colour map

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I have some data in a 2048x2048 array that I want to convert to an image.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image    

path = 'E:\\petra_2018_backup\\final\\raw\data\zn_2_run\\'
file = 'Zn_2_Pos1-01537.tif'   

im = Image.open(path+file)

a = np.array(im)

img = Image.frombytes('CMYK', (2048, 2048), a) # pass in the bytestring
img.save('pic.pdf')
img.show()
```

This result is quite dark and also has a mixture of green and blue colours. I should mention that the attached picture is a screendump of the result as the result picture is to large to attach. [image: Visualisation of the 'a' array]

It would also be usefull if people can advice on a way to compress the resulting image.

Comment: This could be a problem with the dynamic range. What is the range of data you display here? Maybe for visibility it could be helpful to use `log` on the pixel values to see more or remove the high peaks that might cause the majority of the image to be dark. It mostly depends on the nature of the data and what you want to do with it

Comment: What I need this plot to do is to properly show the rings, I have about 100 obtained over different times. I want to reliably format the pictures so that I can make a smal visualisation of how they change over time. I know how to do that, but I want better pictures than the one above. 

Using np.log10 or np.log does not fix the darkness issue and just changes colours slightly.  

I am thinking that Pillow is not the perfect way to solve this

Comment: Could you provide an image as an example, then I could look at it more detailed.
Also I noticed that you use CMYK as color space. Is there a specific reason for that? From the image, it looks like a diffraction experiment of some sorts, so the data should be grayscale. Or is that to save the image with the color map? Have you tried using something like Histogram equalization on the image? What else have you tried?

Comment: It is indeed diffraction data. I am trying to avoid histogram is because command simply takes to long to process. 

Actually greyscale would be ideal. But the reason I used CMYK is that Image.frombytes needs an argument about the enconding and only has the linked options: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.3.x/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes

I would happily provide an example of what I want. But I do not know how to show images in comments.

Comment: I think showing images is not possible in comments. But you could upload it to flickr or something and link to it

Comment: My goal is to reach something like this:
https://www.flickr.com/photos/166586684@N04/shares/6HJM2H
That is made by some diffraction software. But it does not have batch treatming of files. So that is why I am trying do it with python. The blue can be replaced with greyscale or something else.

Comment: Thanks for uploading that image. It seems the data is smoothed and also enhanced, but I don't think I can help you with this. This might be something where you need the actual data and then try several different things, like thresholding or other methods (maybe even specific to the field you're working in.) sorry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply could not find a solution using pillow. So I started using scikit.

Code as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   

path = 'E:\\petra_2018_backup\\final\\raw\data\zn_2_run\\'
file = 'Zn_2_Pos1-01537.tif'

im =io.imread(path+file,as_gray=True)

b = np.array([im],dtype=np.uint16 )
b[b<150]=150  #Modification to array not included in original code
b[b>6000]=6000 #Modification to array not included in original code
c=b.squeeze() 
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax = io.imshow(c)
fig.savefig('result_figure.png',dpi=320)
```

It produces the following plot. [image]